# Color highlight cell values in excel that are under different columns that are named as dates against the date value in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

[image]

I have a data in excel as shown in the attached image. I want to compare the reference date against different date columns and highlight the cells where column header i.e. a date matches with the date given in reference date column for that member.

I tried with conditional formatting using a formula but couldn't compare field values with column names.

Below is the expectation. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=$B2=C$1
```

applied to range:

```
=$C$2:$H$3
```

Result:

[image]

Take a close look at mixed references in formula.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a matter of getting your references set up correctly. If you use `$B2`, it means the column will remain the same to compare/use actions on regardless of which column in the selected range you want to have the rule on but the rows will change depending on the cell in said range.

`C$1` means the opposite, the row will remain the same to compare with but columns will change depending on the cell in the selected range, i.e. for E3, it'll compare $B3 with E$1.

Formula used:

> = $B2 = C$1

[image]

See [more examples here](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/excelformulas/relative-and-absolute-cell-references/1/)

Comment: You're welcome, hopefully the explanation helped understanding.